# Grandchild foreign key

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I'm creating a rest application in Go, and am using GORM for my orm. So far I successfully have everything implemented however I'm now wanting to add some further details to my model in order to make the front end application easier.

This will be adding "grandchildren" foreign keys (Can't think of a better thing to call it). I can't see anything in the documentation about this but effectivly what i'm wanting is the following:

```
type Map struct{
    Id int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Buildings []Building `gorm:"references:Id"`
}

type Building struct{
    Id int  `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    MapId int
    Floors []Floor `gorm:"references:Id"`
}

type Floor struct{
    Id              int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    BuildingId      int
    MapId           int 
}
```

To clarify, I'm unsure how to get the map ID into the database for the Floor struct and from reading documentation I can't seem to find a way of doing this, if anyone can link to some documentation or an example that would be great, please note: I don't want to hold an instance of the map within the floor just the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for people  finding this in the future:

After posting on GORM git page (https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3788) i was directed towards hooks: https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Hooks

My code to solve this is to use a before create for each sub level wgere u then set the approriate values iterativly over the list of sub structs like so:

```
func (building *Building) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error){
    for i := 0; i < len(building.Floors); i++ {
        building.Floors[i].MapId = building.MapId
    }
    return
}
```